# How to configure tomcat-users.xml to secure a page in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, authentication, admin

I'm trying to secure my admin pages in tomcat with `web.xml` and `tomcat-users.xml` but it's not working. The login form appears but connection is impossible

Here is the `web.xml` in my web/WEB_INF folder :

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Admin</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

And `tomcat-users.xml` in the server/tomcat/conf/ folder :

```
<tomcat-users>
   <role rolename="manager"/>
   <role rolename="tomcat"/>
   <role rolename="admin"/>
   <role rolename="role1"/>
   <user username="manager" password="manager" roles="manager"/>
   <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
   <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
   <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
   <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably late to answer but anyways
  You are missing role in in you web.xml and also dont have to mention realm 
 hence you web.xml should look like as follows

```
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
 <login-config>
       <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <!-- Please note following line .. its commented -->
      <!-- <realm-name>Admin</realm-name> -->
 </login-config>
 <!-- Following section was missing -->
 <security-role>
     <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
```