# Securing application using Apache-tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, webserver

I am trying to setup authentication in for Tomcat on unix server. 
Tomcat installed- apache-tomcat-7.0.47.
I have followed the page [How to configure tomcat-users.xml to secure a page in tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818038/how-to-configure-tomcat-users-xml-to-secure-a-page-in-tomcat) 
But then it is only asking for password for the main apache home page and when I enter the password it doesn't work.
Another problem is that it doesn't ask for password for all the applications that are installed under webapps.

Answer (score 0):

JAAS is the framework for you at the root level. Although there are different framework but if you want security at tomcat server level with no third party interference. Go for JAAS.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service

Comment: Is there any other option?

Comment: you can use oauth or spring security at application level. Besides that you can code your own authentication/authorization piece and plug it with tomcat via listeners.