# Difference between HttpServletRequest and SecurityContext

Tags: java, jersey

I am creating a Jersey web service.

A part of Jersey's docs:

> Security information of a request is available by injecting a JAX-RS SecurityContext instance using @Context annotation. The injected security context instance provides the equivalent of the functionality available on HttpServletRequest API.

When using `HttpServletRequest` I can easily do something like this:

```
private @Context HttpServletRequest req;

@Path("/testing")
@POST
public Response testing()
{
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("username", "myusername");
    return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

When using `SecurityContext`, I'm not sure how to retrieve the session and how to save info in it like I did in the method above.

And more generally, when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't retrieve a Session object using SecurityContext. The SecurityContext interface deals with security only whereas the HttpServletRequest provides all information about a particular http(s) request including security.

While you can use a Session object to implement security, this way you're not using any of the servlet's container built in security features.

Both  SecurityContext and HttpServletRequest have a method

```
boolean isUserInRole(String role)
```

which can be used to retrieve the role for a logged in user and do the appropriate action on the server (e.g. return a different resource based on the role )

You can define the roles in web.xml (in case when you're not using SecurityContext)

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/rest/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/rest/orders/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>customer</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        </security-constraint>
        <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>my-default-realm</realm-name>
        </login-config>
```

However, when using SecurityContext you can subclass ResourceConfig and use annotations to add user roles (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html)

```
@Path("/")
@PermitAll
public class Resource {
@RolesAllowed("user")
@GET
public String get() { return "GET"; }

@RolesAllowed("admin")
@POST
public String post(String content) { return content; }
```

Now, even if you explicitly don't call SecurityContext.isUserInRole(role), Jersey will do this check internally. One complete example of using SecurityContext can be found here https://simplapi.wordpress.com/2015/09/19/jersey-jax-rs-securitycontext-in-action/

As for when to use one over the other, use SecurityContext in Jersey (it's easier and more flexible by using annotations only).

Comment: Where is that web.xml file? I don't have it.. Got only the pom.xml of Maven, Hibernate's config file or Config.yml of Jersey.

Comment: It should be in WEB-INF folder. Still, if you're using SecurityContext you don't need to add security related info to your web.xml.

Comment: It's possible that you don't have a web.xml (new servlet specs don't require it as everything can be configured using annotations)

Comment: If you could just add an example of how I can assign a user with a specific role and how I can handle passwords which are sent from a website client, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: A complete example (link to an example) is already given in my answer. Note that the example stores user names, passwords and roles in a database. Of course, you will have to send a user name and password in your request. It's also possible to use your container's authentication/authorization https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/authentication/HttpAuthenticationFeature.html but then you will have to add the roles, names and passwords in user.xml (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818038/how-to-configure-tomcat-users-xml-to-secure-a-page-in-tomcat)