# Unable to access Tomcat manager application using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0, tomcat8

I'm trying to access my manager application using PowerShell script.
Following is the code written so far:

```bsh
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://localhost:8080/manager")
$req.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin", "admin"); 
try
{
    $res = $req.GetResponse()
}
catch [System.Net.WebException]
{
    $res = $_.Exception.Response
}

$int = [int]$res.StatusCode
$status = $res.StatusCode
return "$int $status"
```

I have also made the changes to `tomcat-users.xml` file as you can see below,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui" />
    <role rolename="manager-script" />
    <role rolename="manager-jmx" />
    <role rolename="manager-status" />
    <role rolename="admin" />
    <role rolename="admin-gui" />
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin,admin-gui,manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```

But when I execute the script got the result as `401 Unauthorized`.
What is that I have done wrong here?

Comment: Does your [`web.xml`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15818038/1630171) allow login?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers
Yes , it does.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old but I just encountered this issue. I confirmed the above script will work if you supply the correct tomcat manager address ( http://localhost:8080/manager/html )